# Ordering of Express JS Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I was messing around with Express JS and was the using express-session. It didn't work if I didn't put the `app.use(session())` middleware first

```
app.use(session({
     name: 'server-session-cookie-id',
     secret: 'my express secret',
     saveUninitialized: true,
     resave: true
}));
app.use('/', routes);
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname + "/views"));
app.use(flash());
```

If the `app.use(session())` written first it would say that the `req.session.someVariable`was undefined.

Can someone explain how Express calls the app.use middleware?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All Express route handlers (whether `app.use()`, `app.get()`, `app.post()` or anything else) are checked for a route match in the order they are registered.  Further, once a route sends a request and does not call `next()`, then no further routes are checked for a match to the current request.  All processing for that request will be done.

So, you HAVE to put any middleware BEFORE any requests that want to use the results of that middleware.

Some people think that all `app.use()` handlers might be checked for a match and potentially executed (if they match the request) before any `app.get()` or `app.post()` handlers.  That is not the case.  There's a single handler order in the order they are registered, regardless of which type of handler it is.

> It didn't work if I didn't put the `app.use(session())` middleware first.

If the session middleware isn't before a request handler that wants to use the session, then the session variables won't yet be initialized when that request handler runs and `req.session` itself will be `undefined`.

You have to place the session middleware before any request handler that wants to use the session variables.

Answer (score 3):

In a testing environment, as a pure hack, you can inject middleware at the beginning and bypass the ordering during the initialization.

```
app.use(function test(req, res, next) { next() })
app._router.stack.splice(0, 0, app._router.stack.find(r => r.name === 'test'))
```

Comment: This really helped me - I was able to remove the compression middleware from the router stack. The compression middleware was preventing my server sent events from working when running in the web development server with ReactScripts. The ReactScripts turns on compress with no way to turn it off - Thank you!

Comment: Does this still work? I keep getting an error that layer.match is not a function.