# Express API does not receive file data

Tags: html, typescript, express, ejs, multer

When my form submits, the backend receives the request but does not receive any data. Other endpoints which are JSON only work, but not with form data for some reason.

index.ts:

```
import express, { Request } from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import fs from "fs";
import session from "express-session";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";

import router from "./util/router";

const app = express();

require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.port || 3000;

if(process.env.sentry_dsn) {
    Sentry.init({
        dsn: process.env.sentry_dsn,
        integrations: [
            new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
            new Sentry.Integrations.Express({ app }),
            ...Sentry.autoDiscoverNodePerformanceMonitoringIntegrations()
        ],
        tracesSampleRate: 1.0
    })
}

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler());

app.use(cors<Request>({ origin: "*" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(session({
    secret: require("crypto").randomBytes(64).toString("hex"),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

// Create downloads folder if it doesn't exist
if(!fs.existsSync("./downloads")) fs.mkdirSync("./downloads");

// Connect to Database
import database from "./util/database";
database();

app.use("/", router);

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

app.listen(process.env.port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on Port: ${process.env.port}`);
})
```

util/router.ts:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express";
import SessionData from "../types/SessionData";

const router = Router();
import routes from "./routes";

router.get("/", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.index(req, res);
})

router.get("/admin", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.admin(req, res);
})

router.post("/api/admin/add-user", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.admin.addUser(req, res);
})

router.post("/api/admin/remove-user", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.admin.removeUser(req, res);
})

import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

import File from "../models/File";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) => {
        cb(null, "downloads/"); // Set the destination folder for uploaded files
    },
    filename: async (req: Request, file: any, cb: any) => {
        const id = require("crypto").randomUUID();

        // Save to database
        try {
            await new File({
                id,
                version: req.body.version.toLowerCase(),
                type: req.body.type.toLowerCase(),
                uploaded: Date.now()
            }).save()
        } catch (error) {
            return cb(error);
        }

        cb(null, id + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage }).single("file");

router.post("/api/admin/upload", routes.api.admin.upload, upload, async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "File uploaded successfully.", code: "UPLOAD_SUCCESS" });
})

router.get("/api/auth", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.auth(req, res);
})

router.get("/api/callback", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.callback(req, res);
})

router.get("/api/download/:type/:version", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.download.index(req, res);
})

router.get("/api/download/versions", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.download.versions(req, res);
})

router.get("/api/logout", async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response) => {
    routes.api.logout(req, res);
})

export default router;
```

endpoints/api/admin/upload.ts:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import SessionData from "../../../types/SessionData";

import File from "../../../models/File";

export default async (req: Request & SessionData, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if(!req.session.token) return res.status(401).json({ message: "You are not logged in.", code: "LOGGED_OUT" });
    if(process.env.ownerId !== req.session.user.id) return res.status(401).json({ message: "You are not authorised to use this endpoint.", code: "UNAUTHORISED" });

    if(!req.file) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing file.", code: "MISSING_FILE" });
    if(!req.body.version) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing version.", code: "MISSING_VERSION" });
    if(!req.body.type) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing type.", code: "MISSING_TYPE" });
    if(!["stable", "latest", "beta", "tester"].includes(req.body.type)) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid type.", code: "INVALID_TYPE" });

    const version = req.body.version.toLowerCase();
    const type = req.body.type.toLowerCase();

    // Check if version already exists
    if(await File.exists({ version, type })) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Version already exists.", code: "VERSION_EXISTS" });

    next();
}
```

Frontend:

```
<form id="stable-form">
    <input type="file" accept=".zip" id="stable-file" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Version)" id="stable-version" required>
 
    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold rounded-lg ml-2">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    const stableForm = document.getElementById("stable-form");

    stableForm.addEventListener("submit", uploadStable);

    function uploadStable(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const file = document.getElementById("stable-file");
        const version = document.getElementById("stable-version");

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", file.files[0]);
        formData.append("type", "stable");
        formData.append("version", version.value);

        fetch("/api/admin/upload", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
            stableForm.reset();

            alert(res.message);
        })
    }
</script>
```

I have tried using calling Multer manually in the controller which didn't work as it wouldn't receive data. I have tried commenting out express.json() in the index.ts file, and also commenting out various other parsers, none of which worked.

Comment: router.ts is incomplete please share full code

Comment: You need to register `upload` **before** your route handler... `router.post("/api/admin/upload", upload, routes.api.admin.upload, ...`. This could be closed as a typo or a duplicate of [Ordering of Express JS Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60331843/283366), take your pick

Comment: Also, remove the `content-type` request header. [It's wrong and you don't need it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643919/283366)

Comment: @YuvarajM I have updated it to include the full router.ts code.
@Phil This works now, but how can I protect the endpoint with authentication? Also, I've removed the `Content-Type` request header.